# Cast a IQueryable type to interface in Linq to Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following method in my generic class:

```
// This is the class declaration
public abstract class BaseService<TEntity, TKey> : IBaseService<TEntity, TKey> where TEntity : class, IEntity<TKey>

// The Method
public IQueryable<TEntity> GetActive()
{
    if (typeof(IActivable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TEntity)))
    {
        return this.repository.Get().Cast<IActivable>()
            .Where(q => q.Active)
            .Cast<TEntity>();
    }
    else
    {
        return this.Get();
    }
}
```

This is the interface:

```
public interface IActivable
{
    bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

Basically, `TEntity` is an Entity (POCO) class, that can implement IActivable if they have `Active` property. I want to the method to return all records that have `Active` value true. However, I have this error:

> Unable to cast the type 'WebTest.Models.Entities.Product' to type
>   'Data.IActivable'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM
>   primitive or enumeration types.

I understand why this error occurs. But the articles on SO does not have any valid solution for my case. Is it achievable with `Cast`, or any other way? Note: I do not want to convert to `IEnumerable`, I want to keep `IQueryable`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The EF expression parser will work without casting, however you won't be able to compile the C# code without the casting (C# will complain that it doesn't know that `TEntity` has an `Active` property). The solution is: cast for the c# compiler and not cast for the EF expression parser.

So if you are sure (you are checking it in the `if`, so you are) that the object implements `IActivable`, you can create the expression with the casting (for compiling) and then remove the castings in runtime (which are unnecessary) for EF. For your particular case:

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> GetActive()
{
  if (typeof(IActivable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TEntity)))
  {
    Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> getActive = x => ((IActivable)x).Active;
    getActive = (Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>)RemoveCastsVisitor.Visit(getActive);
    return this.repository.Get().Where(getActive);
  }
  else
  {
    return this.Get();
  }
}
```

The expression visitor is implemented like this:

```
internal class RemoveCastsVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
  private static readonly ExpressionVisitor Default = new RemoveCastsVisitor();

  private RemoveCastsVisitor()
  {
  }

  public new static Expression Visit(Expression node)
  {
    return Default.Visit(node);
  }

  protected override Expression VisitUnary(UnaryExpression node)
  {
    if (node.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert
        && node.Type.IsAssignableFrom(node.Operand.Type))
    {
      return base.Visit(node.Operand);
    }
    return base.VisitUnary(node);
  }
}
```

It just checks if a casting is necessary: if the actual value already implements the type it's casting to, it'll just remove the conversion from the expression, and EF will pick it up correctly.

Comment: Didn't know it was possible to bypass the casting, nice solution!

Comment: Great stuff although naming an interface IActivable is really making me feel queasy! 
Please change it to IActivatable :)

Answer (score 5):

The trick is to cast the whole IQueryable<TEntity> to IQueryable<IActivable> instead of the first cast:

```
if (typeof(IActivable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TEntity)))
{
    return ((IQueryable<IActivable>)(this.repository.Get()))
        .Where(q => q.Active)
        .Cast<TEntity>();
}
```

Comment: Nice and clean solution!

Comment: Is simple, clean and works. Should be the accepted answer IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I have an alternative is to use Extension method. However the downside is that my IBaseService cannot declare the `GetActive` method because the concrete classes do not actually implement it.

```
public static class BaseServiceExtension
{

    public static IQueryable<TEntity> GetActive<TEntity, TKey>(this IBaseService<TEntity, TKey> service) 
        where TEntity : class, IEntity<TKey>, IActivable
    {
        return service.Get().Where(q => q.Active);
    }

}
```