# How can I RemoveAll from List.EntitySet

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am trying to remove all items from a Linq.EntitySet but whatever I tried just removes the items from the list and not from the EntitySet

I saw in other questions that the problem was that the items are removed from the newly created list and not from the original list which is exactly what happen in my code, but none of the answers solved my problem.

What I've tried so far:

This removes the items on list siskevasiaEidous but the items still exists on BisCurrent.SiskevasiesEidousBis

```
List<SiskevasiesEidousBis> siskevasiaEidous = 
                        BisCurrent.SiskevasiesEidousBis.Where(
                            p=> p.ArithmosEidous == Convert.ToInt32(BisCurrent.ArithmosEidous3_32.Value.ToString())).ToList();
```

This code shoes me for example that I have 5 items in that list and the 2 will be removed, but when it runs it does nothing to the list.

```
BisCurrent.SiskevasiesEidousBis.ToList().RemoveAll(a => a.ArithmosEidous == 4);
```

One quite promising code I found which it actually replace the same list without the items that I want to remove

```
BisCurrent.SiskevasiesEidousBis = BisCurrent.SiskevasiesEidousBis.Where(a => a.ArithmosEidous != BisCurrent.ArithmosEidous3_32.Value);
```

It gives me the error :

> Cannot implicity convert type
>   System.Collections.Generic.Ienumerable
>   to
>   'System.Data.Linq.EntitySetAn
>   explicit conversion ecists(are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Try following : BisCurrent.SiskevasiesEidousBis = BisCurrent.SiskevasiesEidousBis.ToList().RemoveAll(a => a.ArithmosEidous == 4);

Comment: @jdweng It gives me error: Cannot implicity convert type'int' to 'System.Data.Linq.EntitySet<Data.Access.Layer.SiskevasiaEidousBis>'

Comment: You are right.  The RemoveAll returns an integer with number of items removed.  You need to use the Where.  The Where you need to add to the end .ToList().

Comment: @jdweng if you mean ```BisCurrent.SiskevasiesEidousBis = BisCurrent.SiskevasiesEidousBis.Where(a => a.ArithmosEidous != BisCurrent.ArithmosEidous3_32.Value).ToList();``` I already tried that . It's the last code I wrote in my question

Comment: If I use ```EntitySet<SiskevasiesEidousBis> siskevasiesEidousBis = BisCurrent.SiskevasiesEidousBis; siskevasiesEidousBis.RemoveAt(indexBis); ``` It removes the specific item from list. But with this code I can just remove one item and not all items

Comment: The following should work : List<EntitySet<SiskevasiesEidousBis>> results = siskevasiesEidousBis.Where(a => a.ArithmosEidous != BisCurrent.ArithmosEidous3_32.Value).ToList();

Comment: @jdweng no, it gives me a similar error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Data.Access.Layer.SiskevasiesEidousBis>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Data.Linq.EntitySet<Data.Access.Layer.SiskevasiesEidousBis>>'

Comment: You can just make it var.

Comment: @jdweng I chnge it to var and now the list has only the items that I want. But how can I pass this list to Biscurent.SiskevasiesEidousBis again?

Comment: Look at Frantisek Bachan solution at this posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34647190/cast-a-iqueryable-type-to-interface-in-linq-to-entities

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for your help. The code you gave me did the work. For the conversion of the IEnumerable to EntitySet I found another post which worked. I will update it in my question.Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @jdweng I found solution to my problem.
The only way I found that works in my program is this:
First I remove all the "unecessary " items by creating a new Generic.List

```
List<SiskevasiesEidousBis> results = BisCurrent.SiskevasiesEidousBis.Where(a => a.ArithmosEidous != BisCurrent.ArithmosEidous3_32.Value).ToList();
```

Second I create a new EntitySet

```
 EntitySet<SiskevasiesEidousBis> es = new EntitySet<SiskevasiesEidousBis>();
```

And finally I fill the EntitySet with the items and pass the EntitySet back to my original List

```
es.AddRange(results);
BisCurrent.SiskevasiesEidousBis = es;
```

I don't know if there is a cleaner code but this works just fine.
Thanks for your help